# Angular UI select2 array with objects is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

Is there a easy way to have options as objects in array? Like following:

```
$scope.search.categories = [{id: '1',name: 'first'},{id: '2',name: 'last'}];

<select ui-select2 ng-model="search.categories" multiple style="width:300px" data-placeholder="select category">
  <option ng-repeat="category in search.categories" value="{{category}}">{{category.name}}</option>

</select>
```

Or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout this demo I've put together: http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:4279651?p=preview

If you want the selected item to be an object use `<input>`

The demo shows you 4 different ways to do uiSelect2

Comment: Is there any way to do this declaratively?

Comment: This library is pretty deprecated. I'd recommend using `ui-select` instead or some other more maintained and lighter solution.

Comment: Th link doesn't exist anymore, could you update it maybe in plain text? Some legacy systems still need this